# Pass vector of lambdas to Poisson(), or guidance on idiomatic function composition

Tags: julia

I'm trying to learn a little Julia by doing some bayesian analysis. In [Peter Hoff's textbook](https://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-0-387-92299-7), he describes a process of sampling from a posterior predictive distribution of a Poisson-Gamma model in which he:

1. Samples values from the gamma distribution
2. Samples values from the poisson distribution, passing a vector of lambdas

Here is what this looks like in R:

```
a <- 2
b <- 1

sy1 <- 217; n1 <- 111

theta1.mc <- rgamma(1000, a+sy1, b+n1)
y1.mc <- rpois(1000, theta1.mc)
```

In Julia, I see that distributions can't take a vector of parameters. So, I end up doing something like this:

```
using Distributions

a = 2
b = 1

sy1 = 217; n1 = 111

theta_mc = rand(Gamma(a+217, 1/(b+n1)), 5000)
y1_mc = map(x -> rand(Poisson(x)), theta_mc)
```

While I was initially put off at the distribution function not taking a vector and working Just Like R™, I like that I'm not needing to set my number of samples more than once. That said, I'm not sure I'm doing this idiomatically, either in terms of how people would work with the distributions package, or more generically how to compose functions.

Can anyone suggest a better, more idiomatic approach than my example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would usually do something like the following, which uses list comprehensions:

```
a, b = 2, 1
sy1, n1 = 217, 111

theta_mc = rand(Gamma(a + sy1, 1 / (b + n1)), 1000)
y1_mc = [rand(Poisson(theta)) for theta in theta_mc]
```

One source of confusion may be that Poisson isn't really a function, it's a type constructor and it returns an object. So vectorization over theta doesn't really make sense, since that wouldn't construct one object, but many -- which would then require another step to call rand on each generated object.

Comment: Ah, I forget that Julia has list comprehensions like Python. Map was just what I reached for. Is there a logic that you know of for making these distributions be constructors rather than functions like in R? Just to avoid (r,d,q)pois naming? Or is there something more awesome I'm missing? e.g. to enable the nifty looking conjugate distribution stuff?

Comment: Having distributions be object means that you express a lot of computations on distributions using only multiple dispatch. The conjugate prior stuff is one example: I can ask for the posterior given a prior distribution and observed data, which reduces to a function from distributions to distributions. Other examples involve doing loops over distributions, where you do a lot of similar things like compute random samples, fit models and look at convergence. Using types makes this kind of programming more generic/abstract.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. And also thank you for all the hard work you're putting into Julia! I see that your name is on most of the packages that I'd be likely to use.